# How to get specific files in SFTP using regex

Tags: linux, regular-expression

I am trying to get files from specific range date (`11-OCT` to `15-OCT`) using SFTP via SecureCRT:

File name: `PEM_CUST_REC_G0X_20181016XXXXXX.gz`

- `*20181016` represents the file date (`YYYYMMDD`).
- `X` represents varied values.

I am doing:

```
#> get PEM_CUST_REC_G0?_201810(1[1-5])*.gz
#> //System could not find specific file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get` command in `sftp` does not understand regular expressions, but can take ordinary filename globbing patterns.

In your case:

```
get PEM_CUST_REC_G0?_2018101[1-5]??????.gz
```

The `?` pattern matches exactly one character and `2018101[1-5]` would match the dates from the 11th to the 15th (inclusively) of October in 2018.

See also the `sftp` manual on your system (`man sftp`).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it works now.